# Redirect high traffic site to new .com url

Tags: redirects, 301-redirect, high-traffic

We're revamping our very high traffic .com.au site (average 80k page views a day) with functionality that we want to offer internationally.  We've purchased a .co and .net url and just weighing up if it's worth using one of them or not.  We already get international traffic to the .com.au site.

Wondering what the potential risks if we redirect, and advantages/disadvantages if we stay and try to run off .com.au  internationally.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding -

A .au site will attract primarily an Australuan audiance. You will get more Google juice from international locations with a .net.  (Im fairly sure that would be the consensus here as well)

IMHO - and I dont have strong evidence, only advice from an SEO expert - The .net will be a lot more credible (so more SEO juice) then a .co domain.

Comment: Apparently .co is the cctld for Columbia, btw.

Comment: According to John Mueller at Google, you can target a global audience with a cctld, it's "perfectly fine" https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZKN8B3yeFAQ#t=44m11s

Comment: It has been a few years since I've seen it tested.  However in the tests I saw it was nearly impossible to get a country code domain to rank globally.    Moving to a generic top level domain increased rankings substantially internationally while hurting rankings within the country a bit.   For John Mueller to be correct, Google has to have changed their policy/algorithms recently.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller It's _possible_, I've seen it done but it takes a ton of time and effort. The people who have done it are also _very_ skilled SEOs, and the countries were in very close proximity. I don't see any reason _why_ you wouldn't just get a gTLD aside from bragging rights.

Comment: The OP says that they have some international rankings with their AU domain. Maybe it isn't worth the risk of switching domain names given that.

Comment: You can certainly rank ccTLDs globally. eg. Search for `.htaccess tester` and 3 of the top 4 results are ccTLDs (and 5 of the top 10, although one of those is a `.io`). @StephenOstermiller

Comment: @davidgo ".co is the cctld for Columbia" - But due to its usage, Google reportedly treats it like a gTLD. https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/crawling/managing-multi-regional-sites